# Google Mobile Ads and LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, adsense

I have managed to run the example file [here](https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/blob/9a4c9342d98c02e3c44e0b62fcfaa153d257130a/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/google/ads/MainActivity.java).  The tutorial for it is [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-%28replaces-deprecated-AdMob%29).

The example file works.

However, I am having trouble placing my own Google details into it,.  I have tried to:

- log into Adsense
- Create an ad unit
- Look at the code for the ad unit to get my publisher id.  It looks like the one in the example i.e. ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
- Append the above with a slash and the ID of the ad unit, which appears to be a 10 digit number.
- Use the resulting string to set the variable AD_UNIT_ID in the example

I did the above last night.

Ads do not appear when I use my AD_UNIT_ID, but they do appear when I use the example ID.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.  I actually needed to go to https://apps.admob.com/ and use their adverts rather than Adsense.